# Is there a way to run a script right after an account deactivated?

Tags: scripting, accounts

What I want to do is create a temporary user like this
 `useradd -m -e 2009-12-01 -c "Temp Account" tempUser` 
so that when the account expires (like this one would on December 1, 2009), the computer will run a script to erase all user data for "tempUser".
Is this possible or are there other ways to remove accounts and user data after they expire?

Comment: login.defs and USERDEL_CMD? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html (just a guess, please doublecheck before using)

Comment: You might want to be more specific on what you mean by expire/deactivated. Do you mean the user expiration that is stored in `/etc/shadow` or some other process that comes along and deletes accounts? If the latter, barrycarter's suggestion works. I would assume the former though, in which case you would need to run a cronjob after midnight each day, looking for accounts that expire on the current day and fire off actions appropriately.

Comment: @JoelDavis He said the expiration date comes from the `useradd -e` option. Is that the date stored in `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: Yeah it is, so I guess he needs to do a daily cronjob. He can iterate over the users with `chage -l <username>` on Linux or iterate over the rows in `passwd -Sa` if he's on Solaris.